# nginx-rtmp-module, authentication, How?

Tags: authentication, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, rtmp

I wonder if self hosted Nginx streaming server which uses nginx-rtmp-module found [here](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module) has any support for any kind of **authentication** (for example only those who had a specific **stream key** would be able to stream to server). My search was pointless since I could n't  find any where to state something about it.
If it does not support, Is there any other way to go around it, for example put the streaming server behind a Nginx proxy and do the job there?
I am completely naive to these topics, help me out please.

Comment: As far as I know there is no native authentication api implemented in nginx-rtmp-module, however you can use on-publish(connect,play) directives to call another custom api (also hosted in your streaming server) to authenticate new streamers. Please refer to https://github.com/Nesseref/nginx-rtmp-auth as an example.

Comment: @mecaf Thanks! Note: the fun nginx/rtmp stuff is in auth.php/auth.py and nginx.conf.